# Register Pipeline Behavior with 3 Type Arguments

Tags: autofac, mediatr

With Mediatr 9, I am trying to register a pipeline behavior that takes an additional type argument.  While it does compile, the pipeline is not getting hit.

Validation Pipeline Signature:

```
public class EnvelopeValidationHandlerAsync<TRequest, TResponse, TRequestItem> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>        
        where TRequest : RequestEnvelope<TRequestItem, Response<TResponse>>
        where TRequestItem : RequestItem, new()
        where TResponse: class
```

Request Signature:

```
public class CreatePatientRequestEnvelope: RequestEnvelope<CreatePatientRequest, Response<PatientResponse>>

public class CreatePatientRequest : RequestItem
```

Request Envelope:

```
 public class RequestEnvelope<TRequestItem, TResponse> : Request<TResponse>, IRequestEnvelope<TRequestItem, TResponse>
        where TRequestItem : IRequestItem, new()
```

Using Autofac, I am registering as:

`containerBuilder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EnvelopeValidationHandlerAsync<,,>)).As(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>));`